# Modern page html branding

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, branding, modern-pages

In a Sharepoint modern page, is it possible to display text when hovered over title like tooltip or similar to using  html tag.

I am also open to using customization options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SharePoint framework extensions application customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions).

Using this mechanism you can control pre-defined placeholders in modern page.

What you are trying to achieve can be done using using JavaScript and CSS, and SharePoint framework extensions application customizer can help you to inject your custom JavaScript and CSS files in your modern page.

You can also take control of your branding by using customized CSS, the same way.

Please check out [this article](https://usefulscripts.wordpress.com/2019/05/03/change-styles-in-sharepoint-online-modern-pages/) which describes the common issues about SharePoint online branding using custom css and the possible options.

Here is a [demo project](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss) to inject a custom CSS.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SPFX solution named "Modern Script Editor Web Part", please check it from here:

[Add The Script Editor Webpart back to SharePoint Modern Experience](https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4)

GitHub Solution download:

[Script editor web part for modern pages built in React](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor)

This script editor web part is similiar with the web part in Classic Page, it's able to addd custom script in it.

If you want to achieve hover tooltip, you can deploy this web part to your tenant and use Jquery tooltip function:

[Jquery Tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)